# jQuery class selector -- what scope does it default to?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a question about the class selector in jQuery.  I'm looking at a page which uses a jQuery plugin called slidedeck, and the page author has two `<div>`s showing two different slidedeck settings.  Along these lines:

```
<div id="slidedeck_frame" class="skin-slidedeck"><dl class="slidedeck">
  <!-...HTML in here-->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.slidedeck').slidedeck({
                autoPlay: true,
                cycle: true, 
                autoPlayInterval: 2500, // 2.5 seconds
                hideSpines: true
            });
</script>

<div id="slidedeck_frame" class="skin-slidedeck"><dl class="slidedeck">
  <!-...HTML in here-->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $('.slidedeck').slidedeck();
</script>
```

So you have two `<div>`s sharing the same ids and CSS classes for their children, but with different slidedeck settings.

I would have thought the jQuery class selector would have applied the last slidedeck setting to both `<dl>`s, but in fact they each use the slidedeck settings directly below them.  I must not be understanding the jQuery selector scope (quite likely), or is there something else at play here possibly?

Comment: You cannot have elements with the same ID in HTML. IDs must be unique;  if there are duplicates, all bets are off.

Comment: Matt-- thanks for the reply.  I realize duplicate HTML IDs are a no-no, but wondered why, given that, jQuery operated as it did.  Sounds like it was almost dumb luck that things worked as they did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate IDs are not valid in HTML. The behavior is not defined.

EDIT

In this case, as you are not using the ID as a selector, your jquery selector should return both of the tags with the class in the selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/cJ4wp/

Answer (score 2):

> I must not be understanding the jQuery selector scope (quite likely)

You are misunderstanding the concept of IDs. ID attributes are meant to be unique across the elements in DOM. I hope that clears it up :)

Comment: Understood, but why would the jQuery CSS selector work the way it does above?